# How does one populate an array in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, methods

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
class Trader

  def initialize(ticker ="GLD") 
    @ticker = ticker
  end

  def yahoo_data(days=12)

    require 'yahoofinance'

    YahooFinance::get_historical_quotes_days( @ticker, days ) do |row|
      puts "#{row.join(',')}"  # this is where a solution is required
    end
  end
end
```

The yahoo_data method gets data from Yahoo Finance and puts the price history on the console. But instead of a simple puts that evaporates into the ether, how would you use the preceding code to populate an array that can be later manipulated as object.

Something along the  lines of :

```
do |row| populate_an_array_method(row.join(',') end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't give a block to `get_historical_quotes_days`, you'll get an array back. You can then use `map` on that to get an array of the results of `join`.

In general since ruby 1.8.7 most iterator methods will return an enumerable when they're called without a block. So if `foo.bar {|x| puts x}` would print the values 1,2,3 then `enum = foo.bar` will return an enumerable containing the values 1,2,3. And if you do `arr = foo.bar.to_a`, you'll get the array `[1,2,3]`.

If have an iterator method, which does not do this (from some library perhaps, which does not adhere to this convention), you can use `foo.enum_for(:bar)` to get an enumerable which contains all the values yielded by `bar`.

So hypothetically, if `get_historical_quotes_days` did not already return an array, you could use `YahooFinance.enum_for(:get_historical_quotes_days).map {|row| row.join(",") }` to get what you want.

Comment: Okay, that was easier than I thought. When I comment the block out, create a new object called 'a' and then call 'a.yahoo_data' I get an array. And by assigning a variable such as 'q = a.yahoo_data', the call of q.class returns 'Array'. q.length returns '8'.